Chrome not showing variable values in debugging mode?
I need some help as to why chrome is not showing varibles values,
Ive scoured everywhere and it seems like its just isolated to just my chrome?
image of chrome debugging
With the image, just pretened my mouse is hovering over customerAccount,
nothing is showing, not even undefined.
Other browsers work fine like firefox.
